# Hard disk contention using multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have not performed any profile testing of this yet, but what would the general consensus be on the advantages/disadvantages of resource loading from the hard disk using multiple threads vs one thread? Note. I am not talking about the main thread.

I would have thought that using more than one "other" thread to do the loading to be pointless because the HD cannot do 2 things at once, and therefore would surely only cause disk contention.

Not sure which way to go architecturally, appreciate any advice.

EDIT: Apologies, I meant to mean an SSD drive not a magnetic drive. Both are HD's to me, but I am more interested in the case of a system with a single SSD drive.

As pointed out in the comments one advantage of using multiple threads is that a large file load will not delay the presentation of a smaller for to the receiver of the thread loader.  In my case, this is a big advantage, and so even if it costs a little perf to do it, having multiple threads is desirable.

I know there are no simple answers, but the real question I am asking is, what kind of performance % penalty would there be for making the parallel disk writes sequential (in the OS layer) as opposed to allowing only 1 resource loader thread? And what are the factors that drive this? I don't mean like platform, manufacturer etc. I mean technically, what aspects of the OS/HD interaction influence this penalty? (in theory).

FURTHER EDIT:
My exact use case are texture loading threads which only exist to load from HD and then "pass" them on to opengl, so there is minimal "computation in the threads (maybe some type conversion etc). In this case, the thread would spend most of its time waiting for the HD (I would of thought), and therefore how the OS-HD interaction is managed is important to understand. My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, multiple threads doing disk I/O in parallel will generally be slower than one thread working on disk I/O sequentially.  The best strategy is usually to have one loading thread which posts completion for each operation.

Comment: It's strongly dependent on OS and hardware. Multiple IO buffers play a role here. More or less if you want to read a chunk of memory from HDD one read sequence will not be interrupted (it's big simplification). You also need to remember that your app is inside living environment multiple apps may try to access HDD. Multiple threads (but not huge number) shouldn't be huge problem. There is also one place where multiple threads will have positive performance. It's when you process multiple files but results are shown instantly. In this case small files will not wait for big files to process.

Comment: If on MS Windows read about IO Completion Ports https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365198(v=vs.85).aspx It provides a managed thread pool with IO request queueing and asynchronous notifications.

Comment: @Logman That's a good point about a big file holding up another smaller file from the receiver, if its a single threaded loader.

Comment: As mentioned, this is highly system dependent AND application dependent. For example, would these threads be hammering the drive or is the I/O intermittent?

Comment: @user3344003 needs to reasonable handle both scenarios.

Answer (score 6):

> Note. I am not talking about the main thread.

Main vs non-main thread makes zero difference to the speed of reading a disk.

> I would have thought that using more than one "other" thread to do the loading to be pointless because the HD cannot do 2 things at once, and therefore would surely only cause disk contention.

Indeed. Not only are the attempted parallel reads forced to wait for each other (and thus not actually be parallel), but they will also make access pattern of the disk random as opposed to sequential, which is much much slower due to disk head seek time.

Of course, if you were to deal with multiple hard disks, then one thread dedicated for each drive would probably be optimal.

---

Now, if you were using a solid state drive instead of a hard drive, the situation isn't quite so clear cut. Multiple threads may be faster, slower, or comparable. There are probably many factors involved such as firmware, file system, operating system, speed of the drive relative to some other bottle neck, etc.

---

In either case, RAID might invalidate assumptions made here.

Comment: Apologies, I meant to mean a SSD drive not a magnetic drive. Both are HD's to me, but I am more interested in the case of a system with a single SSD drive.

Comment: Native Command Queueing, a standard feature of HDDs for a long time now, is designed to rationalise randomly scattered requests into the most efficient sequence of track seeks. So there's no real advantage in making a program make nicely sequential requests. Besides, any assumptions that one FS block is adjacent to another one on the actual disk are not guaranteed either. This is indeed less relevant for SSDs.

Answer (score 1):

A lot people will tell you that an HD can't do more than one thing at once. This isn't quite true because modern IO systems have a lot of indirection. Saturating them is difficult to do with one thread.

Here are three scenarios that I have experienced where multi-threading the IO helps.

1. Sometimes the IO reading library has a non-trivial amount of computation, think about reading compressed videos, or parity checking after the transfer has happened. One example is using `robocopy` with multiple threads. Its not unusual to launch `robocopy` with 128 threads!
2. Many operating systems are designed so that a single process can't saturate the IO, because this would lead to system unresponsiveness. In one case I got a 3% percent read speed improvement because I came closer to saturating the IO. This is doubly true if some system policy exists to stripe the data to different drives, as might be set on a Lustre drive in a HPC cluster. For my application, the optimal number of threads was two.
3. More complicated IO, like a RAID card, contains a substantial cache that keep the HD head constantly reading and writing. To get optimal throughput you need to be sure that whenever the head is spinning its constantly reading/writing and not just moving. The only way to do this is, in practice, is to saturate the card's on-board RAM.

So, many times you can overlap some minor amount of computation by using multiple threads, and stuff starts getting tricky with larger disk arrays.

> Not sure which way to go architecturally, appreciate any advice.

Determining the amount of work per thread is the most common architectural optimization. Write code so that its easy to increase the IO worker count. You're going to need to benchmark.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how much processing of the data you're going to do. This will determine whether the application is I/O you bound or compute bound.

For example, if all you are going to do to the data is some simple arithmetic, e.g. add 1, then you will end up being I/O bound. The CPU can add 1 to data far quicker than any I/O system can deliver flows of data.

However, if you're going to do a large amount of work on each batch of data, e.g. a FFT, then a filter, then a convolution (I'm picking random DSP routine names here), then it's likely that you will end up being compute bound; the CPU cannot keep up with the data being delivered by the I/O subsystem which owns your SSD.

It is quite an art to judge just how an algorithm should be structured to match the underlying capabilities of the underlying machine, and vice versa. There's profiling tools like FTRACE/Kernelshark, Intel's VTune, which are both useful in analysing exactly what is going on. Google does a lot to measure how many searches-per-Watt their hardware accomplishes, power being their biggest cost.

In general I/O of any sort, even a big array of SSDs, is painfully slow. Even the main memory in a PC (DDR4) is painfully slow in comparison to what the CPU can consume. Even the L3 and L2 caches are sluggards in comparison to the CPU cores. It's hard to design and multi-threadify an algorithm just right so that the right amount of work is done on each data item whilst it is in L1 cache so that the L2, L3 caches, DDR4 and I/O subsystems can deliver the next data item to the L1 caches just in time to keep the CPU cores busy. And the ideal software design for one machine is likely hopeless on another with a different CPU, or SSD, or memory SIMMs. Intel design for good general purpose computer performance, and actually extracting peak performance from a single program is a real challenge. Libraries like Intel's MKL and IPP are very big helps in doing this.

*General Guidance*

In general one should look at it in terms of data bandwidth required by any particular arrangement of threads and work those threads are doing.

This means benchmarking your program's inner processing loop and measuring how much data it processed and how quickly it managed to do it in, choosing an number of data items that makes sense but much more than the size of L3 cache. A single 'data item' is an amount of input data, the amount of corresponding output data, and any variables used processing the input to the output, the total size of which fits in L1 cache (with some room to spare). And no cheating - use the CPUs SSE/AVX instructions where appropriate, don't forego them by writing plain C or not using something like Intel's IPP/MKL. [Though if one is using IPP/MKL, it kinda does all this for you to the best of its ability.]

These days DDR4 memory is going to be good for anything between 20 to 100GByte/second (depending on what CPU, number of SIMMs, etc), so long as your not making random, scattered accesses to the data. By saturating the L3 your are forcing yourself into being bound by the DDR4 speed. Then you can start changing your code, increasing the work done by each thread on a single data item. Keep increasing the work per item and the speed will eventually start increasing; you've reached the point where you are no longer limited by the speed of DDR4, then L3, then L2.

If after this you can still see ways of increasing the work per data item, then keep going. You eventually get to a data bandwidth somewhere near that of the IO subsystems, and only then will you be getting the absolute most out of the machine.

It's an iterative process, and experience allows one to short cut it.

Of course, if one runs out of ideas for things to increase the work done per data item then that's the end of the design process. More performance can be achieved only by improving the bandwidth of whatever has ended up being the bottleneck (almost certainly the SSD).

For those of us who like doing this software of thing, the PS3's Cell processor was a dream. No need to second guess the cache, there was none. One had complete control over what data and code was where and when it was there.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the detailed answer. Certainly things to chew over. But as you say, the HD (ssd) being the bottleneck in all this, I was wondering about how mult threading affects the HD-OS interaction. I've updated my question be be more specific in my use case. Thanks.

Comment: @Laythe, I'd say it makes little difference these days. The OS and, if you're using one, the HDD have a lot of features (cache and NCQ) to rationalise random accesses into an optimum traversal of the disk face, specifically so that you don't have to worry too much about it. It's probably quite hard robust... With an SSD it's even less of a worry. But either way you're likely to end up with the SSD as the bottleneck unless you try quite hard, so that really casts doubt on the benefit of using multuple threads in the first place.

Comment: @Laythe, Async disk access can reduce the latency and improve throughput, but only if the disk and OS FS caching has got it wrong and not read ahead for you already.